# $Fr(A\times B)=[Fr(A)\times \overline{B}]\cup [\overline{A}\times Fr(B)]$?

Tags: general-topology

I want to prove this : $$Fr(A\times B)=[Fr(A)\times \overline{B}]\cup [\overline{A}\times Fr(B)]$$
But what i found is that $$Fr(A\times B)=[Fr(A)\times \overset{\circ}{B}]\cup [\overset{\circ}{A}\times Fr(B)]$$

I do like this: \begin{align} Fr(A\times B)&=\overline{A\times B}\setminus \overset{\circ}{\overbrace{A\times B}}\\&= [\overline{A}\times\overline{B}]\cap C_{E\times F}(\overset{\circ}{A}\times\overset{\circ}{B})\\&= [\overline{A}\times\overline{B}]\cap \left[(C_{E}\overset{\circ}{ A}\times \overset{\circ}{B})\cup (\overset{\circ}{A}\times C_{F}\overset{\circ}{B})\cup (C_{E}\overset{\circ}{A}\times C_{F}\overset{\circ}{B})\right]\\&=[(\overline{A}\times \overline{B})\cap(C_{E}\overset{\circ}{ A}\times \overset{\circ}{B})]\cup [ (\overline{A}\times \overline{B})\cap (\overset{\circ}{A}\times C_{F}\overset{\circ}{B})]\cup [(\overline{A}\times \overline{B})\cap(C_{E}\overset{\circ}{A}\times C_{F}\overset{\circ}{B})]\\&=[Fr(A)\times (\overline{B}\cap \overset{\circ}{B})]\cup [(\overline{A}\cap \overset{\circ}{A})\times Fr(B)].   \end{align} 
***Where is The Mistake Please***?

Answer (score 1):

On the final line, you left out the third term, $(\overline{A}\times \overline{B})\cap(C_{E}\overset{\circ}{A}\times C_{F}\overset{\circ}{B})=Fr(A)\times Fr(B)$.  So actually you get $$Fr(A\times B)=[Fr(A)\times (\overline{B}\cap \overset{\circ}{B})]\cup [(\overline{A}\cap \overset{\circ}{A})\times Fr(B)]\cup [Fr(A)\times Fr(B)].$$
Can you show this is equal to $[Fr(A)\times \overline{B}]\cup [\overline{A}\times Fr(B)]$?

Comment: And also use that the intersection of interior and closure is interior and $(C \times D) \cup (C \times F) = C \times (D \cup F)$. And use two copies of the last term..

Comment: Can we say that it is equal to $(Fr(A)\cup \overline{A}) \times (\overline{B}\cup Fr(B)) = \overline{A}\times \overline{B}$ @HennoBrandsma

Comment: @Vrouvrou what is *it* here? I don't see the connection?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma can we say that $Fr(A\times B)=[Fr(A)\times \overline{B}]\cup [\overline{A}\times Fr(B)]=(Fr(A)\cup \overline{A}) \times (\overline{B}\cup Fr(B)) = \overline{A}\times \overline{B}$ ?

Comment: @Vrouvrou Certainly not, the boundary of $A \times B$ does not equal its closure in general. Try simple examples like $(0,1) \times (0,1)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: In any case we can say that $(A\times B)\cup (C\times D)= (A\cup C)\times (B\cup D)$ please @HennoBrandsma

Comment: No, again, trivial examples suffice. You can do it when 1 factor is the same, not otherwise!

Comment: Can you help me to find a counter example please @HennoBrandsma

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32628/discussion-between-henno-brandsma-and-vrouvrou).

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way (I'm not a big fan of messy computations, I rather check inclusions from the definitions) to prove it:

Suppose $(x,y) \in \partial(A \times B)$. Then in particular we know that $(x,y) \in \overline{A \times B} = \overline{A} \times \overline{B}$, so $x \in \overline{A}$ and $y \in \overline{B}$.

If $x \notin (\partial A \times \overline{B}) \cup (\overline{A} \times \partial B)$, this means that $\notin \partial A$, so $x \in \operatorname{int}(A)$ (as $\partial A = \overline{A} \setminus \operatorname{int}(A)$, and we already know $x \in \overline{A}$) and similarly also $y \notin \partial B$ so $y \in \operatorname{int}(B)$. But then $\operatorname{int}(A) \times \operatorname{int}(B)$ is an open neighbourhood of $(x,y)$ that shows $(x,y) \in \operatorname{int}(A \times B)$, which is a contradiction.

On the other hand, suppose $(x,y) \in \partial A \times \overline{B}$ (the other set in the union is dealt with similarly). So $x \in \partial{A}$ and $y \in \overline{B}$. Then let $U \times V$ be any basic open neighbourhood of $(x,y)$. Then $V$ contains a point of $B$ becuse  $y \in V$ and $y \in \overline{B}$, say $b \in B \cap V$, and also  we have both a point $a \in U \cap A$ and a point $b' \in U \cap (E \setminus A)$. But then $(a,b) \in (A \times B) \cap (U \times V)$ and $(b',b) \in (E \times F \setminus (A \times B)) \cap (U \times V)$, and as $U \times V$ was arbitary, $(x,y) \in \partial (A \times B)$. This shows both inclusions.